# How to install Google appengine?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install Google's [appengine](https://developers.google.com/) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Is there an easy method to install it with all dependencies? Is there a PPA?

Comment: this [link](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/web-services/excerpts/9780596800697/run-google-app-linux.html) is quite good.

Comment: but the link above is rather involved... surely there is a nicer way?

Comment: The instructions on the google site work just fine. Why do we need  to duplicate it? Anyhow the whole thing has a series of gengine specific dependencies that are local to only gengine. It's structured so that you can add additional "bundles" and upload them to your instance. Unless google is maintaining the PPA, anyone else doing it would just be playing catchup and adding massive complexity for something that's designed to run out of a single directory. There's no point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install Google App Engine

Extract the zipped file either use the context menu to extract files into a folder.
After you finish extracting, you will get a folder `google_appengine` which has all the necessary files to develop application. To complete the installation and to able to run Google App Engine, we must specify its path definition. You can specify the `PATH` definition in the terminal only using

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/your_user_name/Desktop/google_appengine/
```

But path specified using export command is valid as long as you are inside the current terminal window. That means as soon as you close the window, the path specified becomes invalid. To specify the path in the system, you have to edit

```
/home/your_user_name/.profile
```

and specify the path there.

All set & done, now you have the shiny Google App Engine up & running its time to do the real job. Let us make an ‘Hello World’ application for Google App Engine, using you own Linux Box – excited ? To start using app engine, you have to register an application at

http://appspot.com

That requires your usual Google Account’s credentials and the environment is ready to be used instantly.

this tutorial describes how to develop and deploy a simple Python 2.7 project with Google App Engine.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

Answer (score 10):

Here are the steps I followed to get GAE 1.7.1 working on Ubuntu 12.04.

- open a terminal `Ctr-t` and make sure you are in the home directory.
- create a project folder. (I used `google_projects`)
- cd into the project folder
- download GAE 1.7.1
- unzip the file
- delete the zip. (optional)

Here are the terminal commands for the steps above:

```
    cd ~
    mkdir google_projects
    cd google_projects
    wget -O gae.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.6.zip
    unzip gae.zip
    rm gae.zip
```

Now its time to create the project and start the development server.

```
    cp -r google_appengine/new_project_template testapp
    python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py testapp
```

The first line simply copies and renames the `new_project_template` folder into `google_proects` as `testapp`. The last line starts the development server. You can stop it with `Ctr-C.`

With the development server up and running you can view `testapp` at localhost:8080. You should see "Hello world!".

If you get stuck I have written a [tutorial](http://www.johnogrady.com/blog/2012/09/01/setup-google-app-engine-on-ubuntu/) that covers these steps in more detail. All the best.

Comment: It would be great if you can add the steps here instead of just pasting the link. But still you can mention the link as source: [johnogrady blog](http://www.johnogrady.com/blog/2012/09/01/setup-google-app-engine-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Your right. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 8):

You can install the App Engine Python SDK with [appengine.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appengine), a Python script that automates download and installation.

If you don't have `pip` installed, install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then, install the script:

```
sudo pip install appengine
```

Then install a given `VERSION` of the SDK:

```
appengine.py [--prefix=/path/where/to/install] VERSION
```

Comment: It should be `pip install appengine` instead of `pip install appengine.py` which is invalid, I've edited the line.

Comment: Is there a installer for the AppEngineSDK for PHP?? Im really interested on that, if not i would create mine because is a waste of time doing it with zips and that. The Windows intaller is so much complete and automated than the Linux one. Im afraid with that.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but official way to install it is..

from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

1. exec  <kbd>curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash</kbd>
2. restart shell
3. maximize your shell and exec <kbd>gcloud components list</kbd>
4. install required components with <kbd>gcloud components update</kbd>

   In my case: <kbd>gcloud components update gae-go app</kbd>
5. "appcfg.py" is on your path.

Worked for me on

- Os: Ubuntu 14.04.2
- Date: 2015/06/16