# Google app engine GUI launcher for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, python, google-app-engine

Can someone help me to find GAE launcher for Ubuntu 13.04. I found it for earlier versions of Ubuntu but those PPA's doesn't work for 13.04. I'm using Python version.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine

Comment: No, this is just engine, I need GUI launcher. You don't get GUI launcher by default on Linux, only on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I searched long and hard on this same issue (couldn't actually open the google app engine *launcher* (the GUI) in Ubuntu). The following is the step that helped me to be able to open the GUI.

... But I still am having issues running the app - it has errors. I think it is an issue of (under the Edit/Preferrences menu) *Python Path*, *App Engine SDK Path*, *Editor*, and/or *Deployment Sever*.

http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6004229/google-app-engine-launcher

First you need to install wxPython
open your terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxversion python-wxglade
```

Then you need to download the launcher

in your terminal type :

```
svn checkout
http://google-appengine-wx-launcher.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
google-appengine-launcher
```

now type :

```
cd google-appengine-launcher
```

and simply run your luncher with this command :

```
./GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py
```

or

```
python GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install python-wx stuff using `sudo apt-get install python-wxversion python-wxglade`

Comment: Could you make your answer more verbose? What you expect this to do?